# Using Array.BinarySearch to return a string on a text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently trying to use the inbuilt `Array.BinarySearch` function to search for an item in a listbox. This is for a project so I must do it the required way.

As it stands I am typing information into a text box, right clicking it which brings up a ContextMenuStrip then I should be able to click it which will search the listview for the matching data and populate the other text boxes that go with that piece of data.

If you look in the Image below this will help with the context of what I am doing.

[image]

Here is the code for my `Binary.Search`.

```
        private void text_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Customer findCustomer = new Customer();
            // Value to search for    
            string target = txtCustID.Text;
            int pos = Array.BinarySearch(myCustomer, target);

            if (string.Compare(myCustomer[], target, true) == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Customer found");
                txtCustID.Text = findCustomer.gsCustID;
                txtFullName.Text = findCustomer.gsFullname;
                txtCity.Text = findCustomer.gsFullname;
                txtEmail.Text = findCustomer.gsEmail;
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Customer not found");

        }
```

I currently need something between the brackets on myCustomer[] but I can't figure it out

Comment: How is myCustomer declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In doubt if you want `Array.BinarySearch`. In order to use it you should

1. Have an *array* `Customer[] myCustomer`
2. `Customer` must implement `IComparable<Customer>` interface
3. `myCustomer` must be sorted in *ascending* order
4. You must put `Customer` instance into `Array.BinarySearch` (you can't put just `txtCustID.Text`)

In general case, if you have a collection of `Customer`, e.g.

```
   Customer[] myCustomer = ...
```

you can try *Linq*

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 private void text_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) { 
   // Here, in the FirstOrDefault, we can put any condition
   Customer findCustomer = myCustomer
     .FirstOrDefault(customer => customer.CustId == txtCustID.Text);      

   if (findCustomer != null) {
     // Customer found, (s)he is findCustomer
     MessageBox.Show("Customer found");
     // ...
   }
   else 
     MessageBox.Show("Customer not found"); 
 }
```

**Edit:** If you insist on `Array.BinarySearch` (and all requirements are met, note that `myCustomer` should be *sorted* by `CustId` in *ascending order*) then

```
 private void text_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) { 
   // We prepare artificial Customer to be found 
   Customer customerToFind = new Customer() {
     CustId == txtCustID.Text,  
   };

   int index = Array.BinarySearch(myCustomer, customerToFind);

   if (index >= 0) {
     Customer findCustomer = myCustomer[index];

     MessageBox.Show("Customer found");
     // ...
   }
   else
     MessageBox.Show("Customer not found"); 
 }
```

Comment: I would like to try Linq but because this is for an assignment the requirment is to use the inbuilt Array.Binarysearch, I am normally used to doing Binary search without the inbuilt method, if you could elaborate on Array.binarysearch that would be handy.